# How to add disclaimer if there is an attachment? - Exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange-2010

Currently we have an extremely long disclaimer with two paragraphs. The first paragraph deals with the email content itself. The second paragraph deals with attachments that go out (typically AutoCAD drawings) and how they are to be used/modified and are property of my company, etc., etc.

I'd like to split the disclaimer into two parts - one that is always appended and one that is only appended if there is an attachment on the message.

Is this possible? I've searched on Google, Technet, and here on ServerFault but was unable to find an answer.

Comment: 1. I think a Transport Rule is what you're looking for. 2. Disclaimers are pointless, stupid and of dubious legal merit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need two [Transport Rules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124703(v=exchg.141).aspx) with a [disclaimer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124352(v=exchg.141).aspx) each:

```
# Our disclaimer, with HTML and fancy predicates:
$DisclaimerText = @"
<div style="color: #00FF00; font-family: 'Comic-sans'">
We, here at %%Company%% hate the environment, and want YOU to invest in additional storage!
Please take these extra bytes of HTML as a sign of our gratitude towards your continued support of natural resource depletion
*Patent forms*, *legal threats*, *copyright voodo* Trademark pending
</div><div><img src="http://images.malware.biz/cutepuppy.jpg" /></div>
"@

# Create a new transport rule for mails sent from inside the organization and out
New-TransportRule -Name "LegalDisclaimer" -ApplyHtmlDisclaimerText $DisclaimerText -FromScope InOrganization -SentToScope NotInOrganization
```

The above will apply to all emails sent from your employees to external recipients.

To apply a second disclaimer only in the event that an attachment exists, test if the attachment size exceeds 0 bytes:

```
# Another disclaimer, with HTML and fancy predicates:
$AttachmentText = @"
<div style="color: #FF0000; font-family: 'Comic-sans'">
We, here at %%Company%% still hate the environment, and want YOU to invest in even MORE additional storage!
Please accept this huge attachment in our course of world domination. Thanks in Advance
*Patent forms*, *legal threats*, *copyright voodo* Trademark pending
</div><div><img src="http://images.malware.biz/cutepuppywithhat.jpg" /></div>
"@

# Create a new transport rule with the same scopes, but for only emails with attachments
New-TransportRule -Name "AttachmentDisclaimer" -AttachmentSizeOver 0 -ApplyHtmlDisclaimerText $AttachmentText -FromScope InOrganization -SentToScope NotInOrganization
```

But... don't use it, disclaimers are [***lame***](http://s3.amazonaws.com/theoatmeal-img/comics/email/4.png)

Comment: Gotta love The Oatmeal :)

Comment: Regardless of how The Oatmeal feels about the validity of email disclaimers, I haven't found anything from a legitimate legal source that says they shouldn't be used. Thanks for your reply though, this was a great answer. I hadn't thought about the 'attachment is greater than x size.'